# How can I verify the behavior of docker compose dns?

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-compose

I'm a little confused about container networking in docker compose. If I'm not mistaken, the way it works compose will create a new bridge network, and add all the containers to this new bridge network. Similar to real life bridge, each container will be able to access each others local IP addresses. Furthermore, the bridge network provides a DNS service that allows you to refer to a container by name.
Assuming that's all correct, the part I'm not getting is how can I access and play with this DNS service from inside a container? I can't figure out the mechanism by witch the containers talk to the DNS service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal DNS server is available at `127.0.0.11:53`. You need `dig` command to check it out.

```
apt install -y dnsutils
```

Then you can run the command and query a container by its name inside the container

```
$ dig web @127.0.0.11

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u14-Debian <<>> web @127.0.0.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48886
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;web.               IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
web.            600 IN  A   172.20.0.4

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 26 09:28:40 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Comment: Is there a way to list the services available using `dig` (or anything else) without having to specify them or grep the compose file?